# How to manage multiple configuration files for Octopress?

Tags: jekyll, octopress

I have settings as below in `_config.yml` so that I can get tracking information with the help of GA.

```
# Google Analytics
google_analytics_tracking_id: UA-9118****-2
```

And [this](http://octopress.org/docs/deploying/github/) is how I deploy.

What I want to do is to have two different configurations based on the environments where it runs.

For example)

I hope the value of google_analytics_tracking_id on production is `UA-AAAABBBB-1` and it is `UA-AAAABBBB-2` on localhost.

Are there any approaches to do this without editing the `_config.yml` manually each time I deploy?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `jekyll.environment` variable that is set to **"development"** when you run jekyll locally with `jekyll serve`, and set to **"production"** on github pages.

**_config.yml**

```
google_analytics_tracking_id_dev: UA-9118****-1
google_analytics_tracking_id_prod: UA-9118****-2
```

**In your code :**

```
{% if jekyll.environment == 'production' %}
  {{ site.google_analytics_tracking_id_prod }}
{% else %}
  {{ site.google_analytics_tracking_id_dev }}
{% endif %}
```